# Side view LED 90-degree PCB orientation

Tags: led, pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, footprint

Currently how the LEDs are place on the board, cathode (1) left, anode (2) right, and I am assuming the LED is meant to fire downward, or in this orientation down and mostly left in the 3D model image. Am I correct on this? Does the dot represent firing direction somehow in the land pattern? What about the extra bit of silkscreen, is that the firing side in the PCB model?
What about the symbol?

I think the 2D drawing shows it firing downward, based on the shape of the LED.

What would the best way be to understand this next time? It just seems a little too vague.

I am about 90% sure looking at the manual based on the shape that it is downward firing, but because the shape is oblong. One, I may still be wrong, and two, what if it was a perfect square, how would I know then which way it is sending light?

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ams-osram-usa-inc/LW-Y1SG-BFOO-EKFM-1/6137008

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The silkscreen dot only indicates the cathode, as with any other diode. This is a *right angle* LED, so it definitely isn't downward-firing (those are called "reverse-mount" LEDs).

Comment: Downward as in two d model. In the 2d model, it would fire either up, or down. I know that its 90 degree.

Comment: Well  I guess left or right is easier way to say it with that image. Since I am in pcb design, I mostly view components from their "top."

Answer (score 4):

It's "side view" so it is viewed from the side (looking along or at the edge of the PCB). Image from [Mouser](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/ams-OSRAM/LB-Y1SG-T1U2-35-1?qs=vvQtp7zwQdNdULSQiEaVEQ%3D%3D) (similar product). The LED die is the one in the center of the front and the cavity is filled with silicone and phosphor(s).

[image]

Interestingly, these parts contain a second die, a protection Zener diode to make the part robust against ESD.

OSRAM is a European company and their drawings will be [first angle projection](https://www.gdandtbasics.com/first-vs-third-angle-orthographic-views/). Also standard in Asia.

In response to "What would the best way be to understand this next time?"

Perhaps a bit old-fashioned but I like to have at least one sample of an unusual part where mechanical features matter in-hand before finalizing a PCB layout. It also proves the part is orderable.

Comment: This part in particular I would have gotten wrong, because the oddly-shaped bit on the *opposite* side of where the diode actually is looks to me like a lens in the drawing, which made me think that was the side the light came out of!

Comment: @Hearth Yes, that threw me for a bit, also the dashed lines on the datasheet drawing are a bit confusing, and in way that could tend to confirm that intepretation. It's unclear to me why it has that odd tapered shape in back. Almost as if it is a DFM choice (maybe pops out of the mold easier).

Comment: The shape almost looks like the lens(es) of an IrDA transceiver--perhaps they're reusing an existing mold, or designing it to be handled by some machinery at their factory that was originally designed to deal with IrDA modules?

Comment: Yes, I was pretty 50/50 until I saw the manual, with the drawing shape and the diode. Shame that its not standardized to put a 2d indicator for projected direction.

Comment: @Hearth Come to think of it, since only one side has the cavity, having that an asymmetrical outline would help with orienting it from a bowl feeder.